# why i am unable to access 2 generator object in 1 python code

Tags: python, generator

I am unable to use generator for second time. The object is created fine as a generator but I am not getting any values in the list.

**CODE:**

```
# list of names

names_list = ['Adam','Anne','Barry','Brianne','Charlie','Cassandra','David','Dana']

# too long
# reverse_uppercase = (name[::-1] for name in (name.upper() for name in names_list))

# breaking it up 

upper_case = (name.upper() for name in names_list)

reverse_uppercase = (name[::-1] for name in upper_case)

print("1")

for n in reverse_uppercase:
    print(n)

print('break')

for n in upper_case:
    print("1")
    print(n)

print(upper_case)
print(list(upper_case))
print(reverse_uppercase)
print(list(reverse_uppercase))
```

**Output**:

```
1

MADA

ENNA

YRRAB

ENNAIRB

EILRAHC

ARDNASSAC

DIVAD

ANAD

break

<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f7434874510>

[]

<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f74348744a0>

[]
```

you can see I am trying to acces those generator but I am getting empty list. Please help me.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: You can iterate generator only once, then it is exhausted

Comment: They get exhausted after using it that's why people put list on it so that they can use it many time as they need but this lead to memory consumption. Use generator if you want to use it once other wise store it as a list.

Answer (score 0):

Generators are one-time objects. This means that if you consumed them once, they are "empty".

Answer (score 0):

Your generator `upper_case` is consumed in your first `for` loop, when you consume `reverse_uppercase`. `reverse_uppercase` consumes `upper_case`, because that's how it's defined:

```py
reverse_uppercase = (name[::-1] for name in upper_case)
```

After

```
for n in reverse_uppercase:
    print(n)
```

both generators are empty. If you want to be able to iterate the content multiple times, use a list comprehension instead of a generator expression.